# How to enlarge "fourier" font to match "utopia" package

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling

I'd love to exchange the "obsolete" `utopia` package against the `fourier` package for a couple of reasons.  Unfortunately, the Utopia font in the `fourier` package renders much smaller compared to the `utopia` package.  This looks especially bad when combined with the `avant` package.

Here is a (very) minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{utopia}  % exchange for "fourier" to see the differences

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

Paragraph with a single \textsf{sans-serif} word.

\blindtext{}

\subsection{Subsection title}

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

Look for the size differences between headings and paragraphs as well as the different size of the word *sans-serif* in the first paragraph.

How can I enlarge the Utopia font in `fourier` to get rid of the problem?  Or do you know of other ways to tackle the problem?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to add the package `sectsty`, so the headings were printed in serifs.

Comment: using sectsty makes no difference to my solution with using the tex gyre fonr adventor, which is the free type 1 variant of the non free avantgarde

Comment: @Herbert: I was wondering why you recommended a quite different-looking font, only to find out that it had serifs, looked much like Utopia - and that my headings were not printed in sans-serif.  So that's why I edited my question.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\def\fourierScale{s*[1.2]}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

Paragraph with a single \textsf{sans-serif} word.

\blindtext{}

\subsection{Subsection title}

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I really like your solution, but it unfortunately only works with this special combination of fonts.  What I'm really looking for is a way to enlarge Utopia, not scale AvantGarde down. :)

Comment: replace the three t1fut* files from http://texnik.dante.de/misc/ with your files, then you get a scaled fourier. In your documents preamble you can also modify the scaling with  `\def\fourierScale{s*[1.2]}`. The result of this setting is seen in my edited answer

Answer (score 4):

You can experiment with the `\scalefont` command from the [scalefnt](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=scalefnt) package:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{fourier}  % exchange for "fourier" to see the differences
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}

Paragraph with a single {\scalefont{0.8}\textsf{sans-serif }} word.

\blindtext{}

\subsection{Subsection title}

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```